# Searching for a shorter way to increase an initially unknown attribute in Python

Tags: python

By saying initially unknown, I mean for a class that has many attribute, we may decide which to change on spot.
Like this

```
class Foo:
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0

f = Foo()
```

Now we want to change one of the attribute of the instance by writing the following:

```
# we do a lot of things and get
attr_name = 'a' # well it may be others like 'b' or 'c'
setattr(obj, attr_name, getattr(obj, attr_name) + 1)
```

I personally think this line is not so neat. I wonder if there is a better way

I know we can achieve it by

```
obj.__dict__[attr_name] += 1
```

But I don't know whether touching `dict` is a good idea

**update 1: Sorry that I made a mistake, I meant to write**

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
        self.c = 0
```

**update 2: well I need to explain why I insist on class instead of a neater dict**

In fact I am developing an application using peewee. Thus, to access one column of a row, it will save it as an attribute in the instance. So I have this structure. Since DictField is not supported in peewee, I couldn't have dict solution.

Comment: Shouldn't a, b and c be keys in a dictionary? Why do you have this structure?

Comment: `obj.__dict__[attr_name] += 1` - actually, that won't work, since instances don't have `a`, `b`, or `c` attributes in their `__dict__`s to start with. You're setting class attributes in the class definition, not instance attributes.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry I made a mistake.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich well, in fact I am developing an application using peewee, a field of a model in peewee can be accessed by attribute from an instance. That's why I have this weird structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question is, why are you using a class where a dict would be better,faster,neater.

Secondly as it stands

```
setattr(obj, attr_name, getattr(obj, attr_name) + 1)
```

is totally fine, you could expand it out slightly but thats just semantics.

Edit: response to your edit.

If you are using pewee you are developing something with an sql backend. Do NOT use dynamic columns in a relational database. It might be better to either hard code the columns or you might want to consider storing a json document with these values.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments the best solution would be to use a different data structure (e.g. a dict) which support this kind of operation out of the box.

Alternatively, you can define your solution as a function to make it more expressively:

```
def inc_attr(obj, attr):
    setattr(obj, attr, getattr(f, attr) + 1)


inc_attr(f, 'a')
```